# I want to set the line of an ASCII file equal to a variable in my batch file

Tags: batch-file

On the fifth line of my ascii file called inputfile.txt, which on the 5th line I have I have the following text

```
Filename example_file.txt
```

What I want to do is open inputfile.txt and read the 5th line so that I set up an variable with the filename. The equivalent of the following line:

```
Set "FILENAME=example_file.txt"
```

Any Ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1*" %%A in (inputfile.txt) do (
  set "%%A=%%B"
  goto :break
)
:break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (untested, but the general idea is clear):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('more +5 inputfile.txt') do set "FILENAME=%%b"&goto afterfor
:afterfor
```